# Is it a bad practice to override same static method in child class which is already defined in parent class in Java?

Tags: java, static, polymorphism, overriding

In this piece of code I have declared a parent class Animal containing **static method** eat and a child class of Animal containing same method. I just want to know if if it is a good practice to do this.

```
class Animal{
    public static void eat() {
        System.out.println("Animal Eating");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    public static void eat() {
        System.out.println("Dog Eating");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't override static methods.

Comment: Why static method? the better solution is like Amos mention.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, it is **not** a bad practice. Well your example is a **good** practice instead
2. A better idea is in the parent class we declare the method as [abstract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), since anyway the child class will have its own logic, and the code in the parent class is meaningless.

`

```
class Animal{
    abstract void eat();
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Dog Eating");
    }
}
```

`